# Comparison between high density and low density planting in R

Tags: r, kernel-density

I'm doing germination in high density planting(32 seeds per plot) vs. low density planting(12 seeds per plot) of same 23 varieties. My question here is how can I analyze and show the comparison to highlight the differences of high density vs. low density.

[Image of sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2if7t.png)

I have attached sample data (ID, variety, number of seeds planted and germinated, percent that germinated, and density) for better understanding of data. I want to do my varietal comparison using plant.id.
Thank you in advance for your help.

```
plant.ID variety seeds.planted germinated  percG density
      w1      ab            12          6  50.00      LD
      w2      cd            12          7  58.33      LD
      w3      ef            12          8  66.66      LD
      w4      gh            12          9  75.00      LD
      w5      ij            12         10  83.33      LD
      w6      ab            32         29  90.62      HD
      w7      cd            32         30  93.75      HD
      w8      ef            32         32 100.00      HD
      w9      gh            32         25  78.13      HD
```

Comment: This is a statistics question so more appropriate for cross validated stack exchange

Comment: Link:  [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Please include your data within the post as text, not as an image. You can use `dput` on your dataframe